# Eclipse Debugger Multithreading

Tags: eclipse, multithreading, debugging

Suppose I have a thread inside my application that repeatedly sleeps for x number of seconds until woken up repeatedly by interrupts coming from activity it is monitoring.

Now the number of times it enters sleep can be very large like 50-100 times. And the time it sleeps everytime can be substantial like 20 secs.

So for this thread to come out of this waiting loop, it takes large amount of times thereby inhibiting my ability to debug.

What I would like to ideally do is for me to make Eclipse debugger manually throw InterruptException so that I can wake up the thread much faster each time it enters sleep.

Is this possible with Eclipse debugger?

Comment: Perhaps this is answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205393/force-exception-while-debugging)?

Comment: You're welcome :)  Next time try to search first, your problem may have been someone else's.