# Can a single java thread be killed from jdb?

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, kill, jdb

In theory, the JDB (java debugger) allows for a single thread to be killed. In practice, is it possible? Here I attach jdb to my JVM, which has an agentlib at port 8000:

```
$ jdb -attach 8000
>
```

I list the threads:

```
> threads
Group system:
  (java.lang ...
  [...]
```

I find the thread in question and try to kill it:

```
> kill 0x21bb new java.lang.Exception("die!")
killing thead: pool-766-thread-1
> com.sun.tools.example.debug.expr.ParseException: Unable to create java.lang.Exception instance
Expression must evaluate to an object
```

So threads cannot be killed?

How can one create a new Exception in the jdb, to give it to the thread to die?

Comment: The semicolor does not make a difference (tested it), and the poster in the "here" link that you added also says that he cannot kill the thread either.

Answer (score 1):

The following [answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181615/java-threads-is-it-possible-view-pause-kill-a-particular-thread-from-a-differen/874335#874335) does seems only to *enforce* your question.

**But** the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15911133/101715) probably does answer your question...

Answer (score 0):

It is possible you have jconsole/jvisualvm also running. I had the same issue, but then I closed jconsole, the jdb kill command worked.