# Submitting a background task from spring mvc app

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-mvc

I've got working spring MVC app and what I'm trying to do next is to start or submit a background task from my app.

Basically I'd like to keep the task going until it completes even if the user decides to do something else on the app.

But also I'd like to stop/kill/pause the task if I needed to. Since I haven't done this before I'm looking for a good/better way to do this.

I found these to be useful:

http://blog.springsource.com/2010/01/05/task-scheduling-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/

[How do you kill a thread in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671049/how-do-you-kill-a-thread-in-java)

[Java threads: Is it possible view/pause/kill a particular thread from a different java program running on the same JVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181615/java-threads-is-it-possible-view-pause-kill-a-particular-thread-from-a-differen)

So I wanted to use @Async task to submit my background task, but wanted to use threads' id to obtain it later on and stop it if needed?

Is this the right approach? I don't have any experience with multithreading so I'm here to listen.

**Code update :**

```
public interface Worker {
    public void work();
    public void cancel();
}
```

implementation :

```
@Component("asyncWorker")
public class AsyncWorker implements Worker {

    @Async
    public void work() {
        String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
        System.out.println("   " + threadName + " beginning work");
        try {
                Thread.sleep(10000); // simulates work
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("I stopped");
        }
        System.out.println("   " + threadName + " completed work");
    }

    public void cancel() { Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); }
}
```

Controller for testing purposes :

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping("/job/start")
public String start() {
    asyncWorker.work();
    return "start";
}

@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping("/job/stop")
public String stop() {
    asyncWorker.cancel();
    return "stop";
}
```

When I visit `/job/start`, I can't execute more that one task simultaneously. The other one starts to execute only after first one has completed

Also when I visit `/job/stop` the process isn't stopped, what am I missing here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using thread ID is too low level and brittle. If you decided to use [`@Async` annotation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-annotation-support-async) (good choice) you can use [`Future<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) to control the task execution. Basically your method should return a `Future<T>` instead of `void`:

```
@Async
public Future<Work> work() //...
```

Now you can `cancel()` that `Future` or wait for it to complete:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping("/job/start")
public String start() {
    Future<Work> future = asyncWorker.work();
    //store future somewhere
    return "start";
}

@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping("/job/stop")
public String stop() {
    future.cancel();
    return "stop";
}
```

The tricky part is to store the returned `future` object somehow so it is available for subsequent requests. Of course you cannot use a field or `ThreadLocal`. You can put in session, note however that `Future` is not serializable and won't work across clusters.

Since `@Async` is typically backed by thread pool, chances are your tasks didn't even started. Cancelling will simply remove it from the pool. If the task is already running, you can the `isInterrupted()` thread flag or handle `InterruptedException` to discover `cancel()` call.

Comment: +1 for @Async.  Can you add a link to http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/scheduling.html?

Comment: @Tomasz Nurkiewicz hello thank you for the response. The class actually containing implementation of `fooAsync()` does it need to implement Runnable? if I were to create a cancel method which interrupts thread performing background task, will the Thread.currentThread().interrupt interrupt that particular thread? Can you give an example please?

Comment: @DavidGrant: sure, also you are free to edit any post on SO (which you already did, thanks).

Comment: @GandalfStormCrow: no, that's the beauty, Spring will automatically wrap your method annotated with `@Async` in a runnable proxy. No further changes are required. Check the [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-annotation-support-async). I clarified my post a bit. Also again: `Future.cancel()` does not interrupt any custom thread. It just interrupts this particular `Future<T>` object, the backing thread pool keeps working. Do not create thread per request.

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz I know, but it was quite fundamental, so I wanted to leave it to you ;)