# Kill java thread in Intellij-IDEA debugger

Tags: java, multithreading, debugging, intellij-idea, kill

I've found several posts with instructions of how to kill java thread with **jdb** http://www.rhcedan.com/2010/06/22/killing-a-java-thread/ or [on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181615/java-threads-is-it-possible-view-pause-kill-a-particular-thread-from-a-differen/874335#874335). This works.
Now I want to kill thread with Intellij-IDEA debugger. Is it possible to do?

Comment: Execute System.exit(0).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a little icon on the right side of the Debug view:

[image: Threads icon]

This will open 'Threads' tab and there you can right-click on some of them and select 'Interrupt' (and press F9 if you are sleeping on some breakpoint).

Comment: In order to have the possibility of **Interrupt thread** you have to: `right click on threads` -> `Customize Threads View` -> check  `Show method arguments types`

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is now outdated (at least it is different for me in IntelliJ 2022.3.2). Just in case anyone (like me) stumbles upon it, there is a button at the right side of the debugger that allows you to show threads (it is disabled by default).
see image below:
[image]

Then you'll be able to select the thread you want to modify through the debugger by right clicking it.